# mysql issue in python while using concurrent.futures module

Tags: python

I'm using concurrent.futures module to run jobs in parallel. It runs quite fine.

The start time and completion time gets updated in the mysql database whenever a job starts/ends. Also, each job gets its input files from the database and saves the output files in the database. I'm getting the errors

> "Error 2006:MySQL server has gone away"

and

`"Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query"` while running the script.

I don't face these errors while running a single job.

Sample Script:

```
import concurrent.futures

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=pool_size)

futures = []

for i in self.parent_job.child_jobs:
    futures.append(executor.submit(invokeRunCommand, i))

def invokeRunCommand(self)
    self.saveStartTime()
    self.getInputFiles()
    runShellCommand()
    self.saveEndTime()
    self.saveOutputFiles()
```

I'm using a single database connection and cursor to execute all the queries. Some queries are time consuming ones. Not sure of the reason for hitting this error. Could someone clarify?

-Thanks

Comment: That is not Python. Where do  the `{ }` come from?

Comment: Still not Python. `def` requires a `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a single connection to the database is not thread safe, so if you're using the same database connection for multiple threads, things *will* fail.

If your pseudo code is representative, just start and use a separate database connection for each thread in your `invokeRunCommand` and things should be fine.

Comment: Please let me know whether we need to connect to database for each thread or just creating a cursor per thread using single connection is ok

Comment: @user2194611 You need an entirely separate connection.

Comment: could you pls have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099885/mysql-issue-while-using-concurrent-futures